# Запуск двух Activity

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как запустить сразу две activity? Например, первая (MainActivity) -  это главный экран приложения, а вторая (LockScreenActivity) - должна запускаться вместе с MainActivity, только как лок скрин.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В каждый момент времени работает только одна активити. Все остальные находятся в фоне и не выполняют код, исключая сервисы, запущенные на этих активити и реакции на неявные интенты, на которые подписаны активтити.

Вы можете стартовать со своей `LockScteenActivity` и из нее запускать `MainActivity`, но вместе они не будут работать

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался уже)